# Pass multiple arguments to a decorator in Python

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to build a flask app which will be having RBAC feature. For this I have written a decorator which is working fine but it can only take one argument meaning only one access level(e.g WRITE, READ, admin etc), but I want to pass multiple arguments to it. I have tried passing a list but its not taking it. I have never worked with decorators so need help with it. Thanks.

```py
def permission_required(permission):
  def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
      def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.can(permission):
          abort(403)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
     return decorated_function
   return decorator

def admin_required(f):
  return permission_required(Permission.ADMIN)(f)
```

I as passing it like this:

`@role_needed(Permission.VIEW)`, but I want to have this `@role_needed(Permission.VIEW, Permission.WRITE)`

My permission class is like this:

```py
class Permission:
  VIEW = 'Vew'
  WRITE = 'Write'
  ADMIN = 'admin'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "its not taking it" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd advise that you have a look at some tutorial on decorators, they are pretty cool and you definitely need to understand the basics if you want to use flask. I personally quite like [this RealPython tutorial](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/).

Second, you have two solutions : either default second argument or argument packing.

```py
def permission_required(permission1, permission2=None):
...
```

or

```py
def permission_required(*perms):
...
```

I personaly way prefer the second option.
Example:

```py
def permission_required(*perms):
  def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
      def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        for perm in perms:
            if not current_user.can(perm):
              abort(403)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
     return decorated_function
   return decorator
```

Comment: Yes, you are rightthe article cleared my doubt, I wonder how come I didn't come across it before. Thanks a lot. I fixed the issue

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the point that decorators are just usual functions, taking a function in argument and another one, the later being by design a wrapper around the original one. In your case, `permission_required` is a decorator factory, that can be used to specialize a decorator based on input arguments. So all you need to do is to allow passing any number of arguments to your decorator factory:

```py
def role_needed(*permissions):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal permissions  # Just to make sure `permission` is available in this scope
            # Implement here how to deal with permissions
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator
```

which can be called as intended:

```
@role_needed(Permission.VIEW, Permission.WRITE, ...)
```

In the function, `permissions` will store the input `Permission` as a Python `tuple` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yup I missed that part that is just another python function.